# Command for simulating "enter" button from the user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcl, expect

I'm looking for a way in tcl expect to simulate pressing "enter" the script (for example after some outputs the script stops, and only after I manually press "enter" it goes further) It wait's for a "enter" key to be pressed from the user before continuing outputting the remaining script.

Here is my code where I have this problem:

```
set timeout 20
set f [open "password.txt" r]
set password [read $f]
close $f

foreach i $password {

puts "trying this as a pass : $i"
spawn ssh user@exemple.net -p 724
expect "user@exemple.net's password:"
send $i
interact
}
```

This code takes from the `password.txt` all the words it contains and trye's them as the password for the user@exemple.net;
The code works but after this line from the code above `expect "user@example.net's password:"` I need to press manually "enter" button and then the script goes with the next try.

How can I simulate this enter. Is there any command that simulates it? 
I am new to tcl expect. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The idea of stackoverflow is to help when you stack in coding and dont know how to fix some issue. So, give us some example of code where you wanna simulate enter to completly understand your question.

Comment: @r00t-err0r I have updated the description. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
send $i
```

to

```
send "$i\n"
```

Use this code for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect


# Set the time allowed to wait for a given response. SEt to 30 seconds because it can take a while
# for machines to respond to an ssh request.
set timeout 30000


proc connectToServer { user host password port } {

    set address $user
    append address "@"
    append address $host

    puts "Connecting to server: $host"

    spawn ssh $address -p $port
    expect {
        {*password: } {
            send "$password\n" 
            interact
        }
        {The authenticity of host*} {
            send "yes\n"
            expect {
                {*password: } {
                    send "$password\n"
                    interact
                }
            }
        }
        "*No route to host" { puts "No route to host" }
        eof {puts "Woops there was an eof"}
        timeout {puts "Timed out"}
    }
}


if {$argc < 3} {
    puts "Error - you need to provide at least 3 arguments"
    puts "* user"
    puts "* host"
    puts "* password"
    puts "* port - optional"
} else {
    set user [lindex $argv 0];
    set host [lindex $argv 1];
    set password [lindex $argv 2];

    # setting port argument is optional
    if {$argc > 3} {
        set port [lindex $argv 3];
    } else {
        set port 22
    }

    connectToServer $user $host $password $port
}
```

Comment: I am trying to run your script, but I cant understand were in your code should I write the user host password and port. Your code looks excellent, but how can I run it? Thank you.

Comment: It might need to be `send $i\r` instead. Some terminals care, some don't.

Comment: Typically `\r`, the carriage return, corresponds to the Enter key.